# What is the difference between __reduce__ and __reduce_ex__?

Tags: python, pickle

I understand that these methods are for pickling/unpickling and have no relation to the reduce built-in function, but what's the difference between the 2 and why do we need both?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[The docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__reduce__) say that

> If provided, at pickling time
> `__reduce__()` will be called with no
> arguments, and it must return either a
> string or a tuple.

On the other hand,

> It is sometimes useful to know the
> protocol version when implementing
> `__reduce__`. This can be done by
> implementing a method named
> `__reduce_ex__` instead of
> `__reduce__`. `__reduce_ex__`, when it
> exists, is called in preference over
> `__reduce__` (you may still provide
> `__reduce__` for backwards
> compatibility). The `__reduce_ex__`
> method will be called with a single
> integer argument, the protocol
> version.

On the gripping hand, [Guido says](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2008-February/012094.html) that this is an area that could be cleaned up.

Answer (score 9):

`__reduce_ex__` is what `__reduce__` should have been but never became.  `__reduce_ex__` works like `__reduce__` but the pickle protocol is passed.