# Do `__reduce__` and `__reduce_ex__` just serve for module `pickle`?

Tags: python-3.x

`object` has  `__reduce__` and `__reduce_ex__` out of all 23 meta_methods on the topmost level of inheritance.

```
In [30]: list(enumerate(dir(object), start=1))
Out[30]:
[(1, '__class__'),
 (2, '__delattr__'),
 (3, '__dir__'),
 (4, '__doc__'),
 (5, '__eq__'),
 (6, '__format__'),
 (7, '__ge__'),
 (8, '__getattribute__'),
 (9, '__gt__'),
 (10, '__hash__'),
 (11, '__init__'),
 (12, '__init_subclass__'),
 (13, '__le__'),
 (14, '__lt__'),
 (15, '__ne__'),
 (16, '__new__'),
 (17, '__reduce__'),
 (18, '__reduce_ex__'),
 (19, '__repr__'),
 (20, '__setattr__'),
 (21, '__sizeof__'),
 (22, '__str__'),
 (23, '__subclasshook__')]
```

Reference to various resources to explain the usage and difference of `__reduce__` and `__reduce_ex__`, they conclude that both of them just service a non-builtin module `pickle`.

[What is the difference between **reduce** and **reduce_ex**?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150284/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-reduce-ex)

I am very confused about it.

There exist 23 meta-methods in `object` which consume precious memory space and computation resources of every object in python.

Solely to serve pickle module, added 10% (2/(23-2)) burden to all the atom?

Does they serve for other purpose?

Comment: They don't consume memory on every object in Python, they only exist on the `object` class and don't get copied whenever an instance is made. But still a good question.

Comment: They don't consume computation either, they are loaded once when Python initializes, and then they only get called if you actually use them.